# Command line history in the fish shell suffering from short term memory issues

Tags: command-history, fish

Over the last few months, I've been trying out the `fish` shell as my interactive shell.  One issue that somewhat irritates me is that the shell occasionally forgets recent commands from its command line history.

Let's say I have a personal script in my `$PATH` called `mail-get.sh`.  I can run it by typing its name on the command line and then recall the command at a later time by just typing `get` and pressing <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd>.

Sometimes (a few times a day), the recall fails, and instead, I get *older* commands that happen to contain the string `get`.  The older command may be *several months* older than the most recent invocation of my `mail-get.sh` script.
Using `history merge` at that point always resolves the issue.

Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the issue on purpose.

I have not changed how `fish` should manage its history.  My home directory is not network-mounted. I run several shell sessions in different `tmux` panes at the same time.

I'm most heavily using `fish` version 3.5.1 on FreeBSD.

My question is whether this is something that other users of the shell experience too, and whether it has a known cause and a convenient solution, or whether I should report it as a bug to the `fish` shell project.

Comment: `fish` suffering from short-term memory issues: Have my upvote for a pun'ed title; we need more of these.

Comment: This is quite unusual. One thing which might cause this is if your timezone were to change, or the clock otherwise changes - fish uses the `time(3)` function to decide which items are too new to show, if `time` were to go backwards then some items would not be shown.

Another possibility is the file is corrupt in some way. The history file is typically in `~/.local/share/fish/fish_history`, you can poke around in there to see if anything looks wrong.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish I'm running the ordinary `ntpd` service on the machine, and as far as I can see, it's keeping the time offset to the pool servers within two milliseconds. I never manually step the time. The history file is in no way corrupt, that I can see.  It _feels_ like the shell initially reads the history from the history file and then remembers all old entries but only keeps N new entries.

Comment: I experience this as well, once or twice a day.

Comment: Yeah, me too. I've been using fish for years (on macOS, installed and updated with brew) and this happens to me pretty frequently, probably at least once a week. Right now none of my open shells can find a command I use almost daily. New shells can find it, and `history merge` fixes the situation in old ones.